# R Search for name in nested list and update the name

Tags: r, list, nested-lists

I have a nested list object `cc`. Within the nested list, I want to find if there is item named "StartDate" and update the name to "OccurrenceStartDate".
Right now I am able to rapply to list the names and find the names and manually update. Is there a better way? I need to automate this process.

Also I need to update the format of the OccurrenceStartDate value. I am able to manually assign the format.

```
cc <- list(ConceptSets = list(list(id = 0L, name = "test cs", expression = list(
        items = list(list(concept = list(CONCEPT_ID = 1569193L, CONCEPT_NAME = "Cerebral infarction", 
                                         STANDARD_CONCEPT = "", STANDARD_CONCEPT_CAPTION = "", 
                                         INVALID_REASON = "V", INVALID_REASON_CAPTION = "Valid", 
                                         CONCEPT_CODE = "I63", DOMAIN_ID = "Condition", VOCABULARY_ID = "ICD10CM", 
                                         CONCEPT_CLASS_ID = "3-char nonbill code"), isExcluded = FALSE, 
                          includeDescendants = TRUE, includeMapped = FALSE))))), 
        PrimaryCriteria = list(CriteriaList = list(list(ConditionOccurrence = list(
            CodesetId = 0L, Age = list(Op = "eq", Value = 15L), StartDate = list(
                Op = "bt", Value = structure(17532, class = "Date"), 
                Extent = structure(18628, class = "Date"))))), ObservationWindow = list(
                    PriorDays = 0L, PostDays = 0L), PrimaryCriteriaLimit = list(
                        Type = "First")), QualifiedLimit = list(Type = "First"), 
        ExpressionLimit = list(Type = "First"), InclusionRules = list(), 
        CensoringCriteria = list(), CollapseSettings = list(CollapseType = "ERA", 
                                                            EraPad = 0L), CensorWindow = structure(list(), names = character(0)), 
        cdmVersionRange = ">=5.0.0")

    names(rapply(cc, function(x) head(x)))
    
    names(cc$PrimaryCriteria$CriteriaList[[1]]$ConditionOccurrence)[3] <- "OccurrenceStartDate"
    
    cc$PrimaryCriteria$CriteriaList[[1]]$ConditionOccurrence$OccurrenceStartDate$Value <- cc$PrimaryCriteria$CriteriaList[[1]]$ConditionOccurrence$OccurrenceStartDate$Value %>% format( "%m-%d-%Y")
```

This does not update the names but just lists the names

```
names(rapply(cc, function(x) head(x))) %>% str_replace_all(pattern = "StartDate","OccurrenceStartDate")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with {[data.tree](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html)}:

```
library(data.tree)

## build tree from list:
cc_tree <- FromListSimple(cc)

## update tree in place
cc_tree$Do(function(node) node$name = gsub("StartDate", "OccurrenceStartDate", node$name)) 

## retransform tree to list:
cc_renamed <- ToListSimple(cc_tree)
```

```
## > cc_renamed
$name
[1] "Root"

$cdmVersionRange
[1] ">=5.0.0"

$ConceptSets
$ConceptSets$name
[1] "ConceptSets"

## ...

$PrimaryCriteria$CriteriaList$`1`$ConditionOccurrence$OccurrenceStartDate
$PrimaryCriteria$CriteriaList$`1`$ConditionOccurrence$OccurrenceStartDate$name

## ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `rrapply()` in the `rrapply`-package (extension of base `rapply()`), using the dedicated option `how = "names"`:

```r
library(rrapply)

## rename StartDate -> OccurrenceStartDate
cc1 <- rrapply(cc, condition = \(x, .xname) .xname == "StartDate", f = \(x) "OccurrenceStartDate", classes = "list", how = "names")

## filter OccurrenceStartDate node
str(rrapply(cc1, condition = \(x, .xname) .xname == "OccurrenceStartDate", classes = "list", how = "prune"))
#> List of 1
#>  $ PrimaryCriteria:List of 1
#>   ..$ CriteriaList:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ ConditionOccurrence:List of 1
#>   .. .. .. ..$ OccurrenceStartDate:List of 3
#>   .. .. .. .. ..$ Op    : chr "bt"
#>   .. .. .. .. ..$ Value : Date[1:1], format: "2018-01-01"
#>   .. .. .. .. ..$ Extent: Date[1:1], format: "2021-01-01"
```

---

**Update**: for partially named nested lists, `how = "names"` assigns blank (`""`) names to previously unnamed list elements. To avoid this behavior, we can use instead:

```
cc1 <- rrapply(
  cc, 
  condition = \(x) "StartDate" %in% names(x), 
  f = \(x) { names(x)[match("StartDate", names(x))] <- "OccurrenceStartDate"; x },
  classes = c("list", "ANY"), 
  how = "recurse"
)
```

which will only modify the list elements that satisfy the `condition` argument.

Comment: The rraaply function updates the name but it is changing the structure of the list. So when I have to feed the data to my application I am getting error. If you compare the json format of cc vs cc1 there is some difference in structure that is causing issue.

jsonify::to_json(cc1) not same structure as jsonify::to_json(cc)

Comment: I updated the answer, this should only modify the names of the list elements satisfying the `condition` argument.